# What is the best way to keep a sorted list in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to keep a sorted list in Python. I will be inserting elements in the list in sorted order. I am aware of the bisect module. However, using a regular python list means shifting all elements to the right when I insert an element. I would like to avoid this performance hit. Neither do I want to resort the list with sorted() every time an element is inserted. Is there a data structure similar to Guava's (Java) TreeMultiset in Python?

Comment: depending on your task you could use heapq module

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rbtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rbtree/) which should meet your requirements.